# How to show one column value in two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show status column value in two different columns as `oldstatus` and `newstatus` as shown here.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
      assetno VARCHAR(10),      
      status VARCHAR(30),
      statusid VARCHAR(10),
      cdate DATE
)
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO #Data (assetno, status, statusid, cdate)
VALUES ('M1008', 'NOT READY', '302', '2019-06-03 18:53:51.643' ),
       ('M1008', 'INACTIVE', '302', '2019-06-03 18:56:07.83' ),
       ('M1008', 'EMREVIEW', '304', '2019-06-03 19:09:55.61' ),
       ('M1008', 'INACTIVE', '402', '2019-06-03 19:16:20.707'),
       ('M1008', 'EMREVIEW', '403', '2019-06-03 19:16:37.347'),
       ('M1008', 'NOT READY', '404', '2019-06-03 19:18:57.607'),
       ('M1008', 'EMREVIEW', '405', '2019-06-04 11:28:02.007'),
       ('M1008', 'OPERATING', '502', '2019-06-04 11:31:17.143'),    
       ('M1008', 'NOT READY', '802', '2019-06-06 11:03:32.14'),     
       ('M1008', 'INACTIVE', '603', '2019-06-04 11:37:10.117'),
       ('M1008', 'EMREVIEW', '3782', '2019-07-15 16:35:38.793'),        
       ('M1008', 'NOT READY', '3579', '2019-07-11 18:27:08.567'),
       ('M1008', 'OPERATING', '4178', '2019-07-18 22:07:18.513'),
       ('M1008', 'OPERATING', '2602', '2019-06-26 17:56:39.983');
```

The output needs to look like this:

```
assetno  oldstatus  newstatus                     cdate
-------  ---------  ---------                     -------
M1008   NOT READY   ---             2019-06-03 18:53:51.643         
M1008   NOT READY   INACTIVE        2019-06-03 18:56:07.83      
M1008   INACTIVE    EMREVIEW        2019-06-03 19:09:55.61      
M1008   EMREVIEW    INACTIVE        2019-06-03 19:16:20.707     
M1008   INACTIVE    EMREVIEW        2019-06-03 19:16:37.347     
M1008   EMREVIEW    NOT READY       2019-06-03 19:18:57.607     
M1008   NOT READY   EMREVIEW        2019-06-04 11:28:02.007     
M1008   EMREVIEW    OPERATING       2019-06-04 11:31:17.143     
M1008   OPERATING   NOT READY       2019-06-06 11:03:32.14      
M1008   NOT READY   INACTIVE        2019-06-04 11:37:10.117     
M1008   INACTIVE    EMREVIEW        2019-07-15 16:35:38.793     
M1008   EMREVIEW    NOT READY       2019-07-11 18:27:08.567     
M1008   NOT READY   OPERATING       2019-07-18 22:07:18.513     
M1008   OPERATING   OPERATING       2019-06-26 17:56:39.983
```

Comment: This looks like you just need `LEAD`/`LAG`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: you probably can do this with [LEAD/LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples)

Comment: Your `CDATE` has a time portion - you should therefore be using datatype `DATETIME2(3)`. The just the date store in your `DATE` column, you're losing the ability to properly **sort** the rows!

Comment: Why is the row with `Cdate = '2019-06-26 17:56:39.983'` your final row?? This doesn't make sense - that row should show up earlier on - the row with the max date is  `Cdate = '2019-07-18 22:07:18.513'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this *should* work - if your SQL Server version is recent enough (SQL Server **2012** or newer required):

```
SELECT  
    assetno,
    oldstatus = LAG(status, 1, '---') OVER (ORDER BY Cdate),
    newstatus = status,
    cdate       
FROM 
    #data
ORDER BY 
    cdate
```

As I said in comments - you really should use `DATETIME2(3)` for your `CDate` column - otherwise, your ordering will be unpredictable, if there are several rows with the same date (that differ only in time - but with `DATE`, the time is discarded and not stored).

I get this output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @marc_s, I used the statusid field for order